# Material-UI tab indicator does not change when previous button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

as far as now my code is working fine : The tab indicator is moving accordingly to the url of my tab.
But there's a strange behaviour happening when the back button of the browser is getting pressed, the url is changing but the indicator stay on the same tab as before.

Here's the code :

Tried so far :
Using multiple conditions comparing url (not working) :

```
Thanks to anyone who can help :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `value` is fully dependent on `path`, perhaps consider to always get `value` from `pathname`, instead of saving it as a state and handle both.

This example handles `pathname` with `useLocation`, so it gets updated by the hook when path changes. `value` is generated based on `pathname`.

Example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Tabs, Tab, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { HOME_PAGE } from "../../../router/customRouter";

const navigationsListTabs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    path: "/dev",
    label: "Dev",
    isDisable: false,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    path: "/images",
    label: "Images",
    isDisable: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: "/services",
    label: "Services",
    isDisable: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    path: "/users",
    label: "users",
    isDisable: true,
  },
];

export const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  //  Get value from pathname instead of saving it as state
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const currentTab = navigationsListTabs.find(
    (tab) => tab.path === `/${pathname.split("/")?.pop()}`
  );
  const value = currentTab ? currentTab?.id : 0;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigate("/dev");
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    const selectedTab = navigationsListTabs.find((tab) => tab.id === newValue);
    navigate(HOME_PAGE + selectedTab.path);
  }
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          data-testid="tabs-menu-component"
        >
          {navigationsListTabs.map((item) => (
            <Tab
              key={item.id}
              value={item.id}
              label={item.label}
              aria-label={item.label}
              disabled={item.isDisable}
            />
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```